# Azure Service Bus Disaster recovery for messages

Tags: azureservicebus

Azure Service bus premium tier doesn't allow message replication in case of geo-disaster. Availability zones provide replication across data centers within a region but are not enabled for all regions right now. In the event of disaster no replication is provided across regions, how service bus ensures messages are not lost or Is it to be managed by the developer?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-outages-disasters

Standard tier says about active-active active-passive. But in our scenario we need premium subscription and paired regions solution seems incomplete since messages are not replicated.

Answer (score 0):

Disaster Recovery is supported for metadata plane only (queue, topics, and subscriptions). It is not supported for data plane (actual messages). The latter will be coming in the future to complete disaster recovery story. Standard tier does not support DR and unlikely to support it in the future. In general, standard tier is more suitable for development, testing, and low risk scenarios.

Note that Disaster Recovery features are only available with the premium tier of Azure Service Bus.

Comment: Thanks for reply Sean......But is there any solution for message replication that developers generally follow in case of disaster recovery (any architectural solution?)......or any recommendation that azure suggests?

Comment: Disaster recovery is a broker side feature. Are you trying to build a server-side feature on a client side?

Comment: Since server side feature for message replication is not available right now.....Need to figure out a client side solution.

Comment: If you were able to send two messages to two different data centres in an atomic fashion, then you'd be able to. But you'll be using the same broker to try to implement this feature. And the broker does not expose this functionality. Unless you use external storage, you will not succeed.

Comment: @user818146 something like this is what you're after: https://blog.nilayparikh.com/azure/messaging/cloud-architecture-patterns-high-availability-and-disaster-recovery-for-azure-service-bus/